# Find characters that are similar glyphically in Unicode?

Tags: unicode, glyph

Lets say I have the characters Ú, Ù, Ü. All of them are similar glyphically to the English U.

Is there some list or algorithm to do this:

- Given a Ú or Ù or Ü return the English U
- Given a English U, return the list of all U-similar characters

I'm not sure if the code point of the Unicode characters is the same across all fonts?
If it is, I suppose there could be some easy way and efficient to do this?

**UPDATE**

If you're using Ruby, there is a gem available [unicode-confusable](https://github.com/janlelis/unicode-confusable) for this that may help in some cases.

Comment: Yes, and so are ∪ U+222A UNION and ⋃ U+223C N-ARY UNION and ⩌ U+2A4C CLOSED UNION WITH SERIFS and Ｕ U+FF35 FULLWIDTH LATIN CAPITAL LETTER U and a whole lot more.  What are you trying to do? U, Ù, Ú, Û, Ü, Ũ, Ū, Ŭ, Ů, Ű, Ų, Ư, Ǔ, Ǖ, Ǘ, Ǚ, Ǜ, Ȕ, Ȗ, ᵁ, Ṳ, Ṵ, Ṷ, Ṹ, Ṻ, Ụ, Ủ, Ứ, Ừ, Ử, Ữ, Ự, Ⓤ, ....

Comment: possible duplicate of [Converting Symbols, Accent Letters to English Alphabet.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1008802/converting-symbols-accent-letters-to-english-alphabet)

Comment: Have you looked at the unidecode module? http://pypi.python.org/pypi/Unidecode

Comment: The Unicode concept of "confusables" is also worth mentioning here; see [a demo](http://unicode.org/cldr/utility/confusables.jsp?a=%C3%99a%C3%85&r=None), [full list](http://www.unicode.org/Public/security/revision-02/confusables.txt), and the [technical report](http://www.unicode.org/reports/tr39/).

Comment: @Shervin I was about to comment the same, but realized that the `confusables` are almost exact lookalikes and not the accented versions. (like: )

Comment: @karatedog Correct. I agree that only looking at confusable might not cut it, but it [provides](http://unicode.org/cldr/utility/character.jsp?a=%C3%99&B1=Show) Ù → U +  ̀. Easier way to get such information might be [normalization](http://demo.icu-project.org/icu-bin/nbrowser?t=%C3%99&s=&uv=0).

Comment: I think that *if* you are treating the result as if there are some kind of relationship between the input and the output (beside looks), then I think you need know the language of the input. For example, in Swedish an `Å` is *not* an `A` with a ring modification, it is a separate character. `A` is as different from `Å`, as `A` is different from `B`. In contrast to `e` and `ê`, where the later is an`e` with a circumflex modification.  Sorting in Swedish is like this: `[A], [B], [C], [EÉÈÊË], [X], [Y], [Z], [Å], [Ä], [Ö]`, where all chars within the same brackets should be treated as the same.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

This won't work for all conditions, but one way to get rid of most accents is to convert the characters to their decomposed form, then throw away the combining accents:

```
# coding: utf8
import unicodedata as ud
s=u'U, Ù, Ú, Û, Ü, Ũ, Ū, Ŭ, Ů, Ű, Ų, Ư, Ǔ, Ǖ, Ǘ, Ǚ, Ǜ, Ụ, Ủ, Ứ, Ừ, Ử, Ữ, Ự'
print ud.normalize('NFD',s).encode('ascii','ignore')
```

#### Output

```
U, U, U, U, U, U, U, U, U, U, U, U, U, U, U, U, U, U, U, U, U, U, U, U
```

To find accent characters, use something like:

```
import unicodedata as ud
import string

def asc(unichr):
    return ud.normalize('NFD',unichr).encode('ascii','ignore')

U = u''.join(unichr(i) for i in xrange(65536))
for c in string.letters:
    print u''.join(u for u in U if asc(u) == c)
```

#### Output

```
aàáâãäåāăąǎǟǡǻȁȃȧḁạảấầẩẫậắằẳẵặ
bḃḅḇ
cçćĉċčḉ
dďḋḍḏḑḓ
eèéêëēĕėęěȅȇȩḕḗḙḛḝẹẻẽếềểễệ
fḟ
 :
etc.
```

Comment: i sure hope your source text doesn't include æ, or em dashes, or CJK text, or emoji, or any of the tens of thousands of other characters in Unicode that aren't related to English letters.

Answer (score 33):

It is very unclear what you are asking to do here.

- There are characters whose **canonical decompositions** all start with the same base character: e,  é, ê, ë, ē, ĕ, ė, ę, ě, ȅ, ȇ, ȩ, ḕ, ḗ, ḙ, ḛ, ḝ, ẹ, ẻ, ẽ, ế, ề, ể, ễ, ệ, e̳, … *or* s, ś, ŝ, ş, š, ș, ṡ, ṣ, ṥ, ṧ, ṩ,  ….
- There are characters whose **compatibility decompositions** all include a particular character: ᵉ, ₑ, ℯ, ⅇ, ⒠, ⓔ, ㋍, ㋎, ｅ, … *or* s, ſ, ˢ, ẛ, ₨, ℁, ⒮, ⓢ, ㎧, ㎨, ㎮, ㎯, ㎰, ㎱, ㎲, ㎳, ㏛, ﬅ, ﬆ, ｓ, … *or* R, ᴿ, ₨, ℛ, ℜ, ℝ, Ⓡ, ㏚, Ｒ, ….
- There are characters that **just happen to look alike** in some fonts: ß and β and ϐ, *or* 3 and Ʒ and Ȝ and ȝ and ʒ and ӡ and ᴣ, *or* ɣ and ɤ and γ, *or* F and Ϝ and ϝ, *or* B and Β and В, *or* ∅ and ○ and 0 and O and ০ and ੦ and ౦ and ૦, *or* 1 and l and I and Ⅰ and  ᛁ and | and  ǀ and ∣, ….
- Characters that are the same **case-insensitively**, like s and S and ſ, *or* ss and Ss and SS and ß and ẞ, ….
- Characters that all have the same **numeric value**, like all these for the value *1*: 1¹١۱߁१১੧૧୧௧౧౹౼೧൧๑໑༡၁႑፩១៱᠑᥇᧑᧚᪁᪑᭑᮱᱁᱑₁⅟ ① ⑴ ⒈ ⓵ ❶➀➊꘡꣑꤁꧑꩑꯱  Ⅰⅰꛦ㆒㈠㊀.
- Characters that all have the same **primary collation strength**, like all these that are the same as *d*: DdÐðĎďĐđ◌ͩᴰᵈᶞ◌ᷘ◌ᷙḊḋḌḍḎḏḐḑḒḓⅅⅆⅮⅾ Ⓓ ⓓ ꝹꝺＤｄ     . Note that some of those are not accessible through any kind of decomposition, but only through the DUCET/UCA values; for example, the fairly common ð or the newish ꝺ can be equated to d only through a primary  UCA strength comparison; same with  ƶ and z, ȼ and c, etc.
- Characters that are same in certain **locales**, like æ and ae, *or* ä and ae, *or* ä and aa, or  MacKinley and McKinley,  ….  Note that locale can make a really big difference, since in some  locales both c and ç are the same character while in others they are not; similarly for n and ñ, *or* a and á and ã, ….

Some of these can be handled.  Some cannot. All require different approaches depending on different needs.

What is your real goal?

Comment: +1 to all of it, but mostly "What is your real goal?"! Knowing that is necessary to find the correct approach!

Answer (score 6):

Why not just compare glyphs with something like this?

```
package similarglyphcharacterdetector;

import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Font;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import java.awt.Rectangle;
import java.awt.font.FontRenderContext;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.LinkedHashMap;
import java.util.Map;

public class SimilarGlyphCharacterDetector {

    static char[] TEST_CHARS = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz1234567890".toCharArray();
    static BufferedImage[] SAMPLES = null;

    public static BufferedImage drawGlyph(Font font, String string) {
        FontRenderContext frc = ((Graphics2D) new BufferedImage(1, 1, BufferedImage.TYPE_BYTE_GRAY).getGraphics()).getFontRenderContext();

        Rectangle r= font.getMaxCharBounds(frc).getBounds();

        BufferedImage res = new BufferedImage(r.width, r.height, BufferedImage.TYPE_BYTE_GRAY);
        Graphics2D g = (Graphics2D) res.getGraphics();
        g.setBackground(Color.WHITE);
        g.fillRect(0, 0, r.width, r.height);
        g.setPaint(Color.BLACK);
        g.setFont(font);
        g.drawString(string, 0, r.height - font.getLineMetrics(string, g.getFontRenderContext()).getDescent());
        return res;
    }

    private static void drawSamples(Font f) {
        SAMPLES = new BufferedImage[TEST_CHARS.length];
        for (int i = 0; i < TEST_CHARS.length; i++)
            SAMPLES[i] = drawGlyph(f, String.valueOf(TEST_CHARS[i]));
    }

    private static int compareImages(BufferedImage img1, BufferedImage img2) {
        if (img1.getWidth() != img2.getWidth() || img1.getHeight() != img2.getHeight())
            throw new IllegalArgumentException();
        int d = 0;
        for (int y = 0; y < img1.getHeight(); y++) {
            for (int x = 0; x < img1.getWidth(); x++) {
                if (img1.getRGB(x, y) != img2.getRGB(x, y))
                    d++;
            }
        }
        return d;
    }

    private static int nearestSampleIndex(BufferedImage image, int maxDistance) {
        int best = Integer.MAX_VALUE;
        int bestIdx = -1;
        for (int i = 0; i < SAMPLES.length; i++) {
            int diff = compareImages(image, SAMPLES[i]);
            if (diff < best) {
                best = diff;
                bestIdx = i;
            }
        }
        if (best > maxDistance)
            return -1;
        return bestIdx;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        Font f = new Font("FreeMono", Font.PLAIN, 13);
        drawSamples(f);
        HashMap<Character, StringBuilder> res = new LinkedHashMap<Character, StringBuilder>();
        for (char c : TEST_CHARS)
            res.put(c, new StringBuilder(String.valueOf(c)));
        int maxDistance = 5;
        for (int i = 0x80; i <= 0xFFFF; i++) {
            char c = (char)i;
            if (f.canDisplay(c)) {
                int n = nearestSampleIndex(drawGlyph(f, String.valueOf(c)), maxDistance);
                if (n != -1) {
                    char nc = TEST_CHARS[n];
                    res.get(nc).append(c);
                }
            }
        }
        for (Map.Entry<Character, StringBuilder> entry : res.entrySet())
            if (entry.getValue().length() > 1)
                System.out.println(entry.getValue());
    }
}
```

Output:

```
AÀÁÂÃÄÅĀĂĄǍǞȀȦΆΑΛАѦӒẠẢἈἉᾸᾹᾺᾼ₳Å
BƁƂΒБВЬḂḄḆ
CĆĈĊČƇΓЄГСὉℂⅭ
...
```

Comment: What delicious hack. I doubt it's going to correctly say that `I`, `l` and `1`  or `0`, `o` and `O` are all different though in most fonts, while still saying all those `B`-like things are the same.

Comment: Hey, how did I stumble into Code Golf?!