# Removing diacritical marks using Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, text, diacritics

I have a couple of text files with characters which has diacritical marks, for example `è`, `á`, `ô` and so on. I'd like to replace these characters with `e`, `a`, `o`, etc

How can I achieve this in Python? Grateful for help!

Comment: `text.replace('é','e')`

Comment: Put your replacements in a dictionary, open the text files and use an answer from https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2400504/easiest-way-to-replace-a-string-using-a-dictionary-of-replacements

Comment: This question should be closed, because the problem has answers in StackOverflow. If it is about how to open a text file, or how to replace in string, there are sufficient answers around. That's why I give -1

Comment: you should use the complete unicode homographs table just to make sure you dont miss any, taken from this answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9491890/is-there-a-list-of-characters-that-look-similar-to-english-letters

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Try unidecode (you may need to install it).

```
>>> from unidecode import unidecode
>>> s = u"é"
>>> unidecode(s)
'e'
```

Answer (score 2):

Example of what you could do:

```
 accented_string = u'Málaga'
`enter code here`# accented_string is of type 'unicode'
 import unidecode
 unaccented_string = unidecode.unidecode(accented_string)
 # unaccented_string contains 'Malaga'and is of type 'str'
```

A very similar example of your problem. Check this:
[What is the best way to remove accents in a Python unicode string?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/517923/what-is-the-best-way-to-remove-accents-in-a-python-unicode-string)

Answer (score 1):

In Python 3, you simply need to use the `unidecode` package. It works with both lowercase and uppercase letters.

Installing the package: (you may need to use `pip3` instead of `pip` depending on your system and setup)

```
$ pip install unidecode
```

Then using it as follows:

```
from unidecode import unidecode

text = ["ÉPÍU", "Naïve Café", "EL NIÑO"]

text1 = [unidecode(s) for s in text]
print(text1)
# ['EPIU', 'Naive Cafe', 'EL NINO']

text2 = [unidecode(s.lower()) for s in text]
print(text2)
# ['epiu', 'naive cafe', 'el nino']
```

Comment: Isn't this just a repeat of [the answer from January, 2018](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48445588/354577)?