# Replace dots in filename Python

Tags: python

im trying to replace all dots (and accents, but's already done) in filename with underscore except extension dot of course.
I saw a lot of solutions but mainly with bash. Cant find for python. Probably I should use regex but dont have much experience here. Below my code:

```
path2 = 'xx'
dicto = {"ą":"a", 
         "ś":"s",
         "ę":"e",
         "ć":"c",
         "ż":"z",
         "ź":"z",
         "ó":"o",
         "ł":"l",
         "ń":"n"}

def find_replace(string, dictionary):
    for item in string:
        if item in dictionary.keys():
            string = string.replace(item, dictionary[item])
    return string

def change_name(path=path2):
    for root, dirs, files in os.walk(path):
        for filename in files:
            if not filename.startswith('~'):
                os.rename(os.path.join(root,filename), os.path.join(root,find_replace(filename, dicto)))


change_name()
```

Comment: You can have a look at the [`unidecode`](https://pypi.org/project/Unidecode/) module for converting your non-Latin unicode letters to plain ASCII.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check out [os.path.splitext](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.path.html#os.path.splitext) and replace dots only in the first part of the filename.

Answer (score 1):

There are a number of existing answers here to remove diacritics from Unicode text in python. There is a `unidecode` library for python3 which does exactly what you need.

[Removing diacritical marks using Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48445459/removing-diacritical-marks-using-python)

[What is the best way to remove accents in a Python unicode string?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/517923/what-is-the-best-way-to-remove-accents-in-a-python-unicode-string)

Comment: @Rafał - This will make your diacritics replacement easier and more robust.  Albeit, the dot issue is still outstanding.  **Use regex**.

Comment: @S3DEV I cant' use unicode, because I cant install new packages. Im asking for regex solution. How should I use it

Comment: @Rafał - Understood. May I suggest updating your question with this requirement, as 2/3 of your answers recommend using the `unidecode` module, as we didn't know you can't install new packages.  Aside, this is an [online regex tool](https://regexr.com/) I've found **very** useful.  And [here is a Python regex tutorial](https://www.w3schools.com/python/python_regex.asp).

Answer (score 1):

Just use [Unidecode](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/Unidecode)

```py
import unidecode

print(unidecode.unidecode('ąśęćżźółń))
```

Output:

```
aseczzoln
```